# Discard an entire (sub)expression on a MathLink link

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, c++

Suppose that an expression like

```
f[something, 12]
```

was sent to a MathLink link, and we need to read off only the second part of `f`, which has a known type (e.g. integer).  How can the first part, `something`, be discarded?  `something` could be an atomic or compound expression of any kind.  I need to do this in C.

Example:

```c
int argc = 2;
if (! MLTestHeadWithArgCount(link, "f", &argc)) {
   // fail
}

// how do I discard the complete next expression here, whether it's atomic or compound?

int i;
MLGetInteger32(link, &i); // get the integer
```

Comment: Should I transfer it to a loopback link, then get rid of the loopback link?

Comment: Hmm, I've completely forgotten about [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18638/12).  I think the right way might be `MLTransferExpression(NULL, link)`, but haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Todd Gayley's response here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18638/12) and trying it out, it can be done using

```c
MLTransferExpression(NULL, link)
```

This will remove one complete (sub)expression form the link.

The code for the example from the question would be

```c
int argc = 2;
if (! MLTestHeadWithArgCount(link, "f", &argc)) {
   // fail
}

MLTransferExpression(NULL, link);

int i;
MLGetInteger32(link, &i); // get the integer
```